# Persistent OAuth session

Tags: oauth, twitter

Is is possible to keep a single OAuth session available across multiple users?

My client wants to add their private tweets on one of their intranet pages. The tweets need to just show up without the need for their employees to authenticate with Twitter. Their employees wouldn't be able to authenticate anyways since they wouldn't know the username/password for the account.

I'm new to OAuth. I've been playing around with it and it seems like the session is only available to the user that initiated it and within a single browser session. When I close the browser, or use a different one, it asks to re-authenticate with Twitter.

Is there anyway to accomplish this without posting public tweets? Client doesn't want their tweets public to people outside of the company.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth as a protocol can time out, however Twitter doesn't accept time sensitive OAuth requests.
In other words the tokens will be live forever and you can take them where you want.

If you hard code then into the page that only employees can see, then their is no need for your client to re-authorize every time.

Comment: Scott, thanks for your answer. I did eventually figure it out after reading more about OAuth and the Twitter API.